# How to disable use of website on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

Display an error page if website is accessed through mobile.

I have already tried

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 768px) {
    html,body { display: none; } 
}
```

and

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    getElementById('body').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: **body** is id on your page or it is ``<body>`` tag?

Comment: <body id="body">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change max-width to **`980px`**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {  
html, body {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code works but I can still access website if I turn on the desktop version in my mobile.

Comment: @Error I have updated my answer, you just need to change that 768px to 980px, because Mobile browsers render the page at a desktop screen width (usually about 980px, though this varies across devices).

Comment: Note that this will also kick in on desktop, if the browser window is small enough (not everything keeps the browser fullscreen). You may be able to add something like `and (pointer: coarse)` to the query to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, visit here to get the best way to check it's a mobile browser [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser).

Secondly, you should attent somethings.
- `body` is a tag name, not a `id` (if you set `<body id="body"> then it's okay`). `getElementById` get an element by their `id` not tag name.
- `getElementById` maybe browser will not understood, right way `document.getElementById`

So in "if check" get from above link, push this code into, it's works

```js
document.querySelector('body').style.display = 'none';
// or
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I visited the link and tried the code given in it but I can still access the website if I turn on the desktop version on my mobile.